# MongoDB update many documents with different timestamps in one update

Tags: mongodb

I have 10000 documents in one MongoDB collection.  I'd like to update all the documents with datetime values that are 1 second apart for each document (so all the date time values are unique and are spaced 1 second apart).  Is there any way to do this with a single update instead of updating each document in turn which results in 10000 distinct update operations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this with a single update statement. There are no expressions which run at the server to allow this type of update. There is a [feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-458) for this but it is not done so it cannot be used.